# Dispersive relation from modified equation Beam-Warming

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm looking at this example regarding dispersive relations from modified PDE equations:
[image]

I'm working with $a=1$. I derived the modified equation, but I don't understand how the author makes the conclusions about the group velocity. After taking Fourier transforms of the modified equation and solving, I have
$$\hat{v}(\xi, t) = [i\xi - \gamma i\xi^3]\hat{v}(\xi, t),$$
for $\gamma = \frac{2h^2 - 3kh + k^2}{6}.$ So, I think the group velocity should be $1 - \gamma \xi^2.$ But this can't be right, because then solving the inequality $1 - \gamma \xi^2 < a = 1$ does not result in the condition $1 < k/h < 2,$ which is what the author has. How does he get these conditions?

Comment: You should get $\hat{v}_t = -(i\xi+\gamma i\xi^3) \hat{v}$, since the Fourier transform of $(-\partial_x + \gamma \partial^3_x) v$ is $(-i\xi + \gamma(i\xi)^3)\hat{v}$. This yields a group velocity of $1+3\gamma\xi^2$ which is $<a=1$ when $\gamma < 0$ or (by solving a straightforward quadratic inequality) $h<k<2h$, as desired.

Comment: @kieransquared I see, thank you for that.